# Suppress candidates suggested by GCC

Tags: gcc, g++, optional-parameters, gcc-warning

I'm using gcc 4.7.2. My code is rather heavy on template and [boost](http://www.boost.org/) usage. When I compile and I've defined or used something ambiguous, I often get error messages that suggest two dozen candidates, usually defined in their separate "in file included from [some deep path]:", with corresponding error messages per candidate on why that particular candidate fails. Especially using boost and templates, even a single error like this becomes completely unintelligible.

My question:

> Is there an option to control how deep the search for suitable candidates goes?

Ideally, I'd like it turned *off*, or at least reduce it to only the first one or two candidates -- the rest of the candidates is usually pretty useless anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [gccfilter](http://www.mixtion.org/gccfilter/) to make template errors much more readable. From the website:

> Features:
>
> - coloring of diagnostic messages (with customizable colors),
> - simplification of templated programs output: removal of "with" clauses, template arguments,
> - inline replacement of template arguments by their values,
> - removal of namespaces,
> - removal of instantiation chains.

Comment: +15: IS awesome! Would be perfect if you could "just" pipe to it instead of call it explicitly, but oh well, can't complain really :) Thanks for this find.