# Boost pretty print for GCC error messages

Tags: gcc, boost, g++, optional-parameters, gcc-warning

I'm using GCC 4.7.2. My code is rather heavy on template, STL and [boost](http://www.boost.org/) usage. When I compile and there is an error in some class or function that is derived from or uses some boost/STL functionality, I get error messages showing spectacularly hideous return types and/or function arguments for my classes/function.

My question:

> Is there a prettyprint type of thing for GCC warnings/errors containing boost/STL types, so that the return types shown in error messages correspond to what I've typed in the code, or at least, become more intelligible?

I have briefly skimmed through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432567/debugging-best-practices-for-c-stl-boost-with-gdb?rq=1), however, that is about GDB rather than GCC...

I've also come across [this pretty printer in Haskell](https://github.com/ailiev/gcc-pretty-print), but that just seems to add structure, not take away (mostly) unneeded detail...

Any other suggestions?

Comment: You could try stlfilt - http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StlFilt

Comment: Was fed up with this as well and built this: https://mqnc.github.io/cpptypeexplorer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [STLfilt](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StlFilt) as mentioned in 'C++ Template Metaprogramming' by David Abrahms & Alesky Gurtovoy.

The book contains a chapter on template message diagnostics. It suggests using the `STLFilt /showback:N` to eliminate compiler backtrace  material in order to get simplified output.

Comment: Neat! Seems to be STL-only though, so no boost...oh well, it sure is better than the standard display.

Answer (score 3):

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025773/supress-candidates-suggested-by-gcc), where someone suggested I try [gccfilter](http://www.mixtion.org/gccfilter/). It's a Perl script that re-formats the output of g++ and colorizes it, shortens it, hides full pathnames, and lots more.

Actually, that suggestion answers this question really well too: it's capable of hiding unneeded detail and pretty-printing both STL and boost types. So: I'll leave this here as an answer too.

The only drawback I could see is that g++ needs to be called from within the script (i.e., piping to it is not possible at the time). I suspect that's easily fixed, and in any case, it's a relatively minor issue.

Comment: One of the package the script is using is no longer there.. the corresponding link given in this webpage is invalid.