# Make gcc stop printing canidates for a operation after a certain number is exceeded

Tags: templates, gcc

When using template libraries like glm, you often accidentally call an operator (like operator*) with 2 arguments for which no definition exists. Gcc will the print ALL signatures for which operator* is defined which can be extremely annoying and time consuming.

Is there any flag for gcc to prevent this behaviour and print only, lets say, 5 candidates?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppress candidates suggested by GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025773/suppress-candidates-suggested-by-gcc)